# How to get the sum of only the negative values in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table showing transactions along with the Receipt No., Mode of Payment, and Amount Tendered. What I need from this table is to get the Receipt Nos. with more than two Cash MOPs that have negative values after being summed up (and still leaving the positive amounts as is). The objective of this report is to show Receipt Nos. with irregularities as these are card loading transactions. Having negative summed up cash values would mean that they were given change, which should not happen.  For example this is what I have:

| Receipt No. | MOP | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | Cash | -100 |
| 0001 | Cash | -70 |
| 0001 | Card | 500 |
| 0002 | Cash | -50 |
| 0002 | Cash | -300 |
| 0002 | E-Wallet | 250 |
| 0003 | Cash | -100 |
| 0003 | Cash | 150 |
| 0003 | Card | 200 |
| 0004 | Cash | -100 |
| 0004 | Cash | 300 |
| 0004 | Card | 200 |

The results would need to be like this

| Receipt No. | MOP | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | Cash | -170 |
| 0001 | Card | 500 |
| 0002 | Cash | -350 |
| 0002 | E-Wallet | 250 |

And here is the query that I have so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM table_1 a
JOIN
(SELECT [Receipt No_]
        ,[MOP]
        ,[Amount]
        FROM table_1
        GROUP BY [Receipt No_]
        ,[MOP]
        ,[Amount]
        HAVING MIN([Amount]) < 0 ) t

        on a.[Receipt No_]=t.[Receipt No_]

        ORDER BY [Receipt No_]


GO
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why `0003` and `0004` are not in the expected result ? Any reason for that ?

Comment: @Squirrel The report only needs to show (card loading) transactions with irregularities (i.e. summed up cash values with a negative amount). The resulting negative amounts would mean that they were given change

Comment: please update your question with this additional condition.

Comment: You have been asking similar questions recently, what happen to those previous questions ? Is it resolved ? Please accept the answer if there is any. If it does not answer your question, please do leave a comment and explain why

Comment: @Squirrel This is for an additional report. I was able to make use of the solutions from my previous questions. Sorry for all the questions, I just started SQL for my first job and am also new to this so things are still confusing for me

Comment: Your editing appears to make earlier suggestions apparently pointless. And again - if you show what you want with the 0003 rows that will add some (but only a little) clarity. There is no MOP column - so why do you use that term? And stop throwing DISTINCT into a query in a random attempt to "fix" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this is a similar solution to that I have provided to your previous question.

Firstly, you identify the receipts that you are interested in, in the `cte`. In this case, `Receipt` with `Cash` and total `Amount` is negative.

After that just join back to your original receipt table.

---

```
with trans as
(
    select receipt_no
    from   receipts
    where  mop = 'Cash'
    group by receipt_no
    having sum(Amount) < 0
)
select r.receipt_no, mop, sum(amount)
from   trans t
       inner join receipts r on t.receipt_no = r.receipt_no
group by r.receipt_no, mop, sign(amount)
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d6b7db6ed5598afb2a6ae96dc8615874)

---

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is to simply include `sign([Amount])` in your Group By

**Example**

```
Select [Receipt No.]
      ,[MOP] 
      ,[Amount] = sum([Amount])
 From  YourTable
 Group By [Receipt No.]
         ,[MOP] 
         ,sign([Amount])
```

**Results**

```
Receipt No. MOP         Amount
0001        Card        500.00
0001        Cash        -170.00
0002        Cash        -350.00
0002        E-Wallet    250.00
0003        Card        200.00
0003        Cash        -100.00
0003        Cash        150.00
0004        Card        200.00
0004        Cash        -100.00
0004        Cash        300.00
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to use a `cte` to identify the values to aggregate and the count of each, and then union the result of this with the remaining positives, filtering where the count matches the criteria and the positive rows' receipt_no is a qualifying row.

```
with n as (
    select distinct [Receipt No.], mop, 
        Sum(amount) over(partition by [Receipt No.], mop) Amount, 
        Count(*) over(partition by [Receipt No.], mop) nc
    from t
    where amount<0
)

select [Receipt No.], mop, amount
from n
where nc>=2
union
select [Receipt No.], mop, amount 
from t
where t.amount>0 
    and exists (select * from n where n.[Receipt No.]=t.[Receipt No.] and n.nc>=2)
order by [Receipt No.], amount
```

Answer (score 0):

Had you included the 0003 rows we would have more clarity about your goal. Do you really want to include the rows with a positive amount as is (without aggregation) and only aggregate the rows with negative amount? That is an unusual goal IME.

But when the goal is described as above, does it not lead you to one possible approach? You can use a union to select all the rows with positive amounts and also to select the aggregated rows for the negative amounts.

```
SELECT [Receipt No_], [Amount Tendered] AS AMOUNT, [Tender Type]
  FROM dbo.table_1 
 WHERE [Amount Tendered] >= 0
UNION ALL
  SELECT [Receipt No_], SUM([Amount Tendered]), [Tender Type]
    FROM dbo.table_1 
   WHERE [Amount Tendered] < 0
   GROUP BY [Receipt No_], [Tender Type]
;
```

I will guess that you probably want that resultset ordered - I leave it to you to do so. Note that I added an assumed schema name to your table as well as a statement terminator - both best practices. I will add that it is not defined what you want if multiple "negative" rows exist with different values for [Tender Type]. Know your data!

Answer (score 0):

You can use union here:

Select rcptno,mop,(sum(amount)×-1) amt
From table
Where amount <0
Group by rcptno,mop

Union

Select rcptno,mop,(sum(amount)) amt
From table
Where amount >0
Group by rcptno,mop

Answer (score -1):

Group by the sign of the amount:

```
...
GROUP BY [Receipt No_]
    ,[Tender Type]
    ,[Amount Tendered]
    ,[Amount Tendered] > 0 -- add this
```